# C# LINQ query shows and exception when datagridview cell is empty

Tags: c#, linq, exception, datagridview, null

Well, I have a button with this code:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        lblAvg.Text = String.Format("Average score: {0:F2}",
            (from GridViewRowInfo row in studentGridView.Rows
             where row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() != string.Empty
             select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].Value)).Average());
}
```

and it works fine if in cells[1] there is at least one number(one cell with number), but if there isn't, return an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
```

So first where is the problem and secondly is there a wiser way to check before get the value, when there's no value at all and it's empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

In your "where" part you should do something like that:

```
lblAvg.Text = String.Format("Average score: {0:F2}", studentGridView == null ? string.Empty : 
 (from GridViewRowInfo row in studentGridView.Rows
              where row.Cells.Count() > 0 && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() != string.Empty
             select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].Value)).Average().ToString());
```

Comment: The result is the same. But if I add at least one new row(when the programs start the grid is empty) the exception comes from "where" line  not from the end of the code. But yeah still shows an exception but this time (System.NullReferenceException)

Comment: => row.Cells.Count() > 0 | "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'double'"

=> row.Cells.Count > 0 |
"GridViewCellInfoCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'GridViewCellInfoCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Fixed it:  i added ToString() at the end.   Why didn't you write: row.Cells.Count()? (with paranthesis)

Comment: Dont't know why but shows an exception(three different cases, but with () not working): http://s3.postimg.org/6x2xwqntv/exc1.png
http://s3.postimg.org/obn650kyr/exc2.png
http://s3.postimg.org/gwxucmz37/exc3.png, btw i'm using radgridview from telerik, but the grid has rows count so that isnt the problem :D

Comment: Well for the problem with converting from string to double is that: ".Average().ToString());" not ".Average()).ToString();" but the exception with the empty grid is stil there

Answer (score 0):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty()` extension method before `.Average()`
In your case it return 0 if not rows exists

Comment: Same exception :( Is there any other way to check if if the grid column is empty and then to get things from it, because seems it this way things are not working